# POLYGON25D WITH OGR2OGR

Tags: ogr2ogr, polygon-creation

I know how to convert a csv file with xyz coords to point25d with ogr2ogr and vrt file
but the coords in the files are the vetices of 3dpolygon (firsth and last ones are the same coords).
I want to convert that files to POLYGON25D with ogr2ogr
How I can do it?

the file has

```
x,y,z

219980.345,1834052.671,741.279
```

---

Comment: After a lot of googling, I've got it

Comment: WKT,CLAVE,NOMBRE  "POLYGON ((219689.796189 1833894.82989 722.433408273,Xn Yn Zn,219693.199289 1833896.67864 724.745782685))","KaceCzDo","LT-03"

Comment: Post the answer in answer section instead of merging it with question.

Answer (score 1):

I've got it. The `.csv` file has the following WKT string:

```
WKT,CLAVE,NOMBRE
"POLYGON ((219689.796189 1833894.82989 722.433408273,Xn Yn Zn,219693.199289 1833896.67864 724.745782685))","KaceCzDo","LT-03"
```

and `.vrt` file has the following string:

```
<OGRVRTDataSource>
    <OGRVRTLayer name="LT3_geol3d">
        <SrcDataSource relativeToVRT="1" shared="1">C:\PROGSCRIPT\CONVERSION\QGIS\LT3_geol3d.csv</SrcDataSource>
        <GeometryType>wkbPolygon25D</GeometryType>
        <GeometryField>encoding="WKT" field="WKT"</GeometryField>
        <LayerSRS>PROJCS[&quot;NAD_1927_UTM_Zone_15N&quot;,GEOGCS[&quot;GCS_North_American_1927&quot;,DATUM[&quot;North_American_Datum_1927&quot;,SPHEROID[&quot;Clarke_1866&quot;,6378206.4,294.9786982]],PRIMEM[&quot;Greenwich&quot;,0.0],UNIT[&quot;Degree&quot;,0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION[&quot;Transverse_Mercator&quot;],PARAMETER[&quot;False_Easting&quot;,500000.0],PARAMETER[&quot;False_Northing&quot;,0.0],PARAMETER[&quot;Central_Meridian&quot;,-93.0],PARAMETER[&quot;Scale_Factor&quot;,0.9996],PARAMETER[&quot;Latitude_Of_Origin&quot;,0.0],UNIT[&quot;Meter&quot;,1.0]]</LayerSRS>
        <Field name="CLAVE" type="String" src="CLAVE" width="10"/>
        <Field name="NOMBRE" type="String" src="NOMBRE" width="10"/>
    </OGRVRTLayer>
</OGRVRTDataSource>
```

and the `ogr2ogr` command line is as follow:

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" c:\path c:\path\file.vrt
```